# How to set invocation count of a test method during execute the method

Tags: java, testng

I want to rerun one test case many times.

I found:

```
@Test(invocationCount=10, threadPoolSize=1)
```

and

```
annotation.setInvocationCount(15);
```

to change times.

But it executed before the case is called. I need to do something in the case then I can know if I need to rerun it or not. Is it possible to change rerun times in the case rather than define it before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `RetryAnalyzer`: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implement-iretryanalyzer-to-retry-failed-test-in-testng-framework/

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        boolean shouldRetry = // business logic
        if(shouldRetry) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi,thank you it works,but the case should be fail then trigger rerun,could it be success also trigger rerun?

Comment: Nope. `invocationCount` doesn't have any listener. But you can fail (by an exception) the case you want to rerun and then use the retry analyzer mechanism.